# How to implement responsive layout in Ant Design form?

Tags: reactjs, layout, antd, ant-design-pro

While working with ant design form, I have serious problem with responsiveness.

```
import { From, Input, Button } from 'antd'
const { Item } = Form;

const layout = {
  labelCol: { span: 8 },
  wrapperCol: { span: 16 },
};

const tailLayout = {
  wrapperCol: { offset: 8, span: 16 },
};

const ExampleAntForm = () => {
{

   return (
      <Form {...layout}>
          <Item label="Name" name="username"> <Input type="text"/> </Item>
          <Item label="Password" name="password"> <Input type="password"/> </Item>
          <Item {...tailLayout}>
              <Button htmlType="submit" type="primary"> Submit </Button>
          </Item>
      </Form>
   )
}
```

But in this case, I'd like to apply layout depending on screen size.

Ideally like below,

```
const layout = {
   labelCol = { span: { sm: 24, md: 8, lg: 6 }}
   wrapperCol = { span: { sm: 24, md: 16, lg: 12 }}
}
```

How to approach this responsiveness using the `layout` props in ant design `Form` component?
Orr just let me know any other potential solutions for my issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can modify layout like below

```
const layout = {
    labelCol: { xs: { span: 24 }, sm: { span: 12 }, md: { span: 8 }, lg: { span: 8 } },
    wrapperCol: { xs: { span: 24 }, sm: { span: 12 }, md: { span: 12 }, lg: { span: 12 } }
}
const tailLayout = {
    wrapperCol: { xs: { span: 24 }, sm: { span: 12, offset: 12 }, md: { span: 12, offset: 8 }, lg: { span: 12, offset: 8 } }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Ant Design predefined layout, it's helpful for making your form responsive automatically,
Here is a link for more info
https://ant.design/components/layout

Comment: thanks for your comment @lamMHC. Can you attach full code example?

Comment: Handle the layout by screen sizes like below

const layout = {
  labelCol: {
    xs: { span: 24 },
    sm: { span: 8 },
  },
  wrapperCol: {
    xs: { span: 24 },
    sm: { span: 16 },
  },
};

breakpoint width
{
  xs: '480px',
  sm: '576px',
  md: '768px',
  lg: '992px',
  xl: '1200px',
  xxl: '1600px',
}